# как через ngFor вывести только первые 4 items

Tags: angular5, angular

в массиве *items* 10 объектов , мне нужно вывести только первые 4 используя переменную size

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="prod-section">
  <div  *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h1>{{ item.id }}</h1>
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  size: number = 4;

  items = [
      { id: 1, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 2, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 3, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 4, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 5, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 6, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 7, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 8, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 9, name: 'плитка' },
      { id: 10, name: 'плитка' },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:size">
    <h1>{{ item.id }}</h1>
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```